# При клике на popup окна на заднем фоне стр пролистывается в вверх сайта, как это убрать

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Пользуюсь плагином magnific-popup
Возникла такая проблема, что при клике на popup окна с фото, или формой обратной связи, стр на заднем фоне пролистывается вверх сайта, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, как это можно убрать

html

```
<a href="#form2" class="button popupone"><span>Заказать</span></a>
```

Подключаю magnific-popup через

```
$(".popupone").magnificPopup();
```

А для скролла использую такой код, может дело в нем?

```
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
// Remove links that don't actually link to anything
.not('[href="#"]')
.not('[href="#nolink"]')
.not('[href="#form"]')
.click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
        && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        // Figure out element to scroll to
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        // Does a scroll target exist?
        if (target.length) {
            // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000, function() {
                // Callback after animation
                // Must change focus!
                var $target = $(target);
                $target.focus();
                if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not
                    focusable
                    $target.focus(); // Set focus again
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Все телепаты в отпуске, поэтому лучше вам наверное сначала код свой попробовать выложить, отредактировав данный вопрос :-)

Comment: @Stanislav Belichenko указал код что использую для скролла )

Comment: Видимо, в `href` ссылки, по которой кликаете, указано '#'

Comment: @Pyramidhea да там надо же как-то открыть попап, и в href идет #, я выложил еще код от кнопки, можете глянуть

Comment: Добавьте `.not('[href="#form2"]')` после `.not('[href="#form"]')`

Comment: @Pyramidhead я пробовал уже, раньше оно поднимало вверх сайта и там оставалось, после того как добавил .not('[href="#form2"]'), оно все равно поднимается, но уже при закрытия popup возвращается обратно к блоку где была нажата кнопка

Comment: Можете попробовать такой подход `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button popupone" data-mfp-src="#form2"><span>Заказать</span></a>`

Comment: @Pyramidhead не помогло

Comment: @АлексейСоколов, что-то я сомневаюсь, что это так. Составьте и опубликуйте здесь минимальный пример, который воспроизводит проблему. Также можете разместить код на jsfiddle.